# encoding from ASCII to Windows-1253

Tags: php, encoding

I am using the following code to write data to a txt file

```
$fp = fopen("textfiles/td_ord.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content_td_ord);
fclose($fp);
```

The text file produced is in ASCII encoding.
Is there a way to convert the file or the data written in Windows 1253?

Comment: Convert Windows 1253 encoded text to ?

Comment: convert ASCII to windows 1253

Comment: I believe ASCII is a subset of windows 1253 and conversion is not necessary, Although you can use stream filter, iconv and others to convert the encoding.